# Render css3 transformed elements to canvas / image

Tags: image, html, css, canvas

Basically, I want to save a certain DOM element of my page as an image, and store this on a server (and also allow the user to save the image to a local disk). I reckon the only way of doing this currently is to render a canvas, which allows me to send the image data via AJAX and also make image elements in the DOM. I found a [promising library](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) for this, however my DOM element has

1. multiple transparent backgrounds
2. css 3d tranforms

And html2canvas simply fails there. Is there currently any way to neatly save an image representation of the current state of a DOM element, with all its CSS3 glory?

Comment: I went through this promising library, documentations and examples, even downloaded it. found the page is converted to dom by html2canvas.Preload( element,  options ); but how to trigger the screenshot and how to save it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers may never allow a DOM element to be truly rendered as it is to a canvas, because there are very serious security concerns around being able to do that.

Your best bet is html2canvas plus your own hacks.  You may simply need to implement your own render code in a customised way.  Multiple backgrounds should be doable with drawImage calls, and you may be able to work in css3 transforms when canvas 2D gets [setTransform()](http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#dom-context-2d-settransform) (which I think is only in the next version of the spec).

Answer (score 1):

In this stage of CSS3 development and crossbrowser support is this probably not possible without writing your own html2canvas extension.

You can try dig into Google Chrome bug reporter as they allow you to send current snapshot of web page. But I think it's some internal function which isn't available in JS api.

Also, I think this can be easily abused for spying on users, so don't expect any official support from browser development teams.